# Is there a better way to select rows from a pandas DataFrame based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select rows from a pandas DataFrame based on multiple conditions. The code looks like this:

```
row = videos_train_df[
             (videos_train_df['pid1']==pid1)
            &(videos_train_df['pid2']==pid2)
            &(videos_train_df['vid'] ==vid)]
```

Is there any better way (in terms of code readability) to do the same thing?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html ?

Comment: Do you find that difficult to read?  I don't, especially the way you've spaced it.  I think the meaning is quite clear.

Comment: @Tim Roberts this particular example isn't too difficult to read, but `df.query` is a nice way to avoid reusing the `videos_train_df` variable name in the condition. Plus there could be 100 conditions instead of 3 conditions and then passing a string to df.query is easier to work with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```py
row = videos_train_df.query(
    f"pid1 == {pid1} and pid2 == {pid2} and vid == {vid}"
)
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/8227062) question.

Comment: That doesn't need quoting?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I will do `all` after `eq`

```
new = df[df[['pid1','pid2','vid']].eq([pid1,pid2,vid]).all(1)]
```